# KNN imputer with nominal, ordinal and numerical variables

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation

I have the following data:

```
# Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import nan_euclidean_distances

# Data set
toy_example = pd.DataFrame(data = {"Color": ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Blue", np.nan],
                                   "Size": ["S", "M", "L", np.nan, "S"],
                                   "Weight": [10, np.nan, 15, 12, np.nan],
                                   "Age": [2, 4, np.nan, 3, 1]})
toy_example
```

I want to impute the variables `Color` (nominal), `Size` (ordinal), `Weight` (numerical) and `Age` (numerical) where I want to use KNN imputer using the distance metric `nan_euclidean` from `sklearn.impute.KNNImputer`

I now that I need to pre-process the data first. Therefore I came up with the following 2 solutions

a. **One hot encoding** for the nominal variable where the `NaN` values are encoded as a category

```
# Preprocessing the data
color_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
color_encoder.fit(X=toy_example[["Color"]])
## Checking categories and names
### A na dummy is included by default
color_encoder.categories_
color_encoder.get_feature_names_out()

# Create a new DataFrame with the one-hot encoded "Color" column
color_encoded = pd.DataFrame(color_encoder.transform(toy_example[["Color"]]).toarray(),
                             columns=color_encoder.get_feature_names_out(["Color"]))
color_encoded

# Create a dictionary to map the ordinal values of the "Size" column to numerical values
size_map = {"S": 1, "M": 2, "L": 3}
size_map
toy_example["Size"] = toy_example["Size"].map(size_map)

# Concatenate encoded variables with numerical variables
preprocessed_data = pd.concat([color_encoded, toy_example[["Size", "Weight", "Age"]]], 
                              axis=1)
preprocessed_data

## Matrix of euclidean distances
matrix_nan_euclidean = nan_euclidean_distances(X=preprocessed_data)
matrix_nan_euclidean

# Perform nearest neighbors imputation
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)
imputed_df = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(preprocessed_data), 
                          columns=preprocessed_data.columns)
## Here I have a problem where the NaN value in the variable
## "Color" in relation to the 5th row is not imputed
### I was expecting a 0 in the Color_nan and a positive value
### in any of the columns Color_Blue, Color_Green, Color_Red
imputed_df
```

As I mention in the comments of the code this solution is not feasible for the case of the nominal variable because I obtain the following result where the nominal variable is not imputed:

```
   Color_Blue  Color_Green  Color_Red  Color_nan  Size  Weight  Age
0         1.0          0.0        0.0        0.0   1.0    10.0  2.0
1         0.0          0.0        1.0        0.0   2.0    13.5  4.0
2         0.0          1.0        0.0        0.0   3.0    15.0  2.5
3         1.0          0.0        0.0        0.0   1.5    12.0  3.0
4         0.0          0.0        0.0        1.0   1.0    12.5  1.0
```

For the case of the ordinal variable at least the value is imputed where I need to decide the appropiate roundig method to apply (classical rounding, ceiling or floor)

b. **One hot encoding** for the nominal variable where the `NaN` values are not encoded as a category and the rest of the dummy variables are considered `NaN`

```
# Preprocessing the data
color_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
color_encoder.fit(X=toy_example[["Color"]])
## Checking categories and names
### A na dummy is included by default
color_encoder.categories_
color_encoder.get_feature_names_out()

# Create a new DataFrame with the one-hot encoded "Color" column
color_encoded = pd.DataFrame(color_encoder.transform(toy_example[["Color"]]).toarray(),
                             columns=color_encoder.get_feature_names_out(["Color"]))
color_encoded
## Don't take into account the nan values as a separate category 
color_encoded = color_encoded.loc[:, "Color_Blue":"Color_Red"]
## Because I don't know in advance the values of the dummy variables
## I will replace them with NaN values which is a logical solution taking
## into account that I don't know the value of this observation in relation
## to the "Color" variable
color_encoded.iloc[4, :] = np.nan
color_encoded

# Create a dictionary to map the ordinal values of the "Size" column to numerical values
size_map = {"S": 1, "M": 2, "L": 3}
size_map
toy_example["Size"] = toy_example["Size"].map(size_map)

# Concatenate encoded variables with numerical variables
preprocessed_data = pd.concat([color_encoded, toy_example[["Size", "Weight", "Age"]]], 
                              axis=1)
preprocessed_data

## Matrix of euclidean distances
matrix_nan_euclidean = nan_euclidean_distances(X=preprocessed_data)
matrix_nan_euclidean

# Perform nearest neighbors imputation
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)
imputed_df = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(preprocessed_data), 
                          columns=preprocessed_data.columns)
## Here I have a problem because I will need to decide
## how to round the values using classical rounding, 
## ceiling or floor in relation to the 5th row. However 
## any of this methods are inconsistent because an 
## observation cannot be Blue and Green at the same time 
## but it needs to be at least Blue, Green or Red
imputed_df
```

As I mention in the comments of the code this solution is not feasible for the case of the nominal variable because I obtain the following result where the nominal variable takes 2 values or doesn't take any value:

```
   Color_Blue  Color_Green  Color_Red  Size  Weight  Age
0         1.0          0.0        0.0   1.0    10.0  2.0
1         0.0          0.0        1.0   2.0    13.5  4.0
2         0.0          1.0        0.0   3.0    15.0  3.5
3         1.0          0.0        0.0   1.5    12.0  3.0
4         0.5          0.5        0.0   1.0    12.5  1.0
```

Taking into account that a. and b. doesn't work, anyone knows how to impute a nominal variable in a consistent way using **multivariate imputation**?

So, how can I impute the observations of the `toy_example` for the case of the nominal variable using **multivariate imputation**?

Comment: what are your shape?  can you drop nan? your preprocessing is good, however you will need use scaler(columns: Weight  and Age). KNN do keen with scaler.

Comment: can you show all data? I will work preprocessing and give you all code. I have free time.

Comment: Thank you @TornikeKharitonishvili for your answer. I know I need to scale the columns Weigth and Age but because this is a toy example I didn't include this step because it is irrelevant for the problem I have. The problem I have is with the nominal varible "Color". In relation to sharing the data please take into account that I create this toy example with the pure objective to understand the KNN imputer. I am going to use this knowledge in a real data set but I can't share this data set because of data privacy.

Comment: In relation to dropping na values this will be the easiest solution but I don't want to lose information in a real context if I can impute the values. So if anyone knows how to impute a nominal variable I will not drop na values but if someone points out that this is impossible I will drop the entire observation with na values in the "Color" column.

Comment: OK, that's understandable.  you need NaN replace. becase you have nominal varible "Color", you need sklear:  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html .  you can use imp = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent") and fill NaN.   most_frequent is used then you have nominal varible. It will fill NaN with the most frequent occurrence.

Comment: Interesting question, I'll follow it. I didn't know it is possible to use KNN on non-numeric data. I was concerned when using ordinal data, the distance between the sizes is not known and KNN relies on distances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again @TornikeKharitonishvili. I had already contemplated this possibility but remember that I want to impute values using knn imputer which is a multivariate imputation. What you mention applies univariate imputation and specifically use the mode to do that. But again thank you for the observation where I am going to specify that in the question more explicitely.

Comment: OK, understand, knn count distance, becase It needs data without NaN. I don't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KNNImputer` is not suited for *categorical* features (both ordinal and nominal), since, as stated in the scikit-learn [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html):

> Each sample’s missing values are imputed using the **mean value** from `n_neighbors` nearest neighbors found in the training set.

It uses the mean of the neighbors while you need the *mode* instead, or a category in general.

What you can do is: use the `KNNImputer` as a pre-processing step to impute numerical features first, then train a [classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier.html) that handles NaN, one for each categorical feature. In your case you have `Color` and `Size`, so two classifiers are needed.

I tried the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

# Data set
toy_example = pd.DataFrame(data = {"Color": ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Blue", np.nan],
                                   "Size": ["S", "M", "L", np.nan, "S"],
                                   "Weight": [10, np.nan, 15, 12, np.nan],
                                   "Age": [2, 4, np.nan, 3, 1]})
size_map = {"S": 1, "M": 2, "L": 3}
color_map = {'Blue': 1, 'Red': 2, 'Green': 3}


# 1. Convert categories to integers (i.e. class labels)
toy_example["Size"] = toy_example["Size"].map(size_map)
toy_example['Color'] = toy_example["Color"].map(color_map)
toy_example
   Color  Size  Weight  Age
0    1.0   1.0    10.0  2.0
1    2.0   2.0     NaN  4.0
2    3.0   3.0    15.0  NaN
3    1.0   NaN    12.0  3.0
4    NaN   1.0     NaN  1.0

# 2. Use the KNN imputer for numerical features only, like weight and age
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2, weights='distance')  # or 'uniform'
y = imputer.fit_transform(toy_example.values)

toy_example['Weight'] = y[:, 2]
toy_example['Age'] = y[:, 3]
toy_example
   Color  Size     Weight  Age
0    1.0   1.0  10.000000  2.0
1    2.0   2.0  13.500000  4.0
2    3.0   3.0  15.000000  3.0
3    1.0   NaN  12.000000  3.0
4    NaN   1.0  11.306019  1.0

# 3. Train a classifier to impute color and size (nominal and ordinal)
# training data and targets (size)
x_size = toy_example.values[:, [0, 2, 3]]
y_size = toy_example.values[:, 1]

# discard entries with nan
is_nan = np.isnan(y_size)

x_train = x_size[~is_nan]
y_train = y_size[~is_nan]

# Train classifier and impute size
clf = HistGradientBoostingClassifier(l2_regularization=1.0).fit(x_train, y_train)

toy_example.loc[is_nan, 'Size'] = clf.predict(x_size[is_nan])
toy_example
   Color  Size     Weight  Age
0    1.0   1.0  10.000000  2.0
1    2.0   2.0  13.500000  4.0
2    3.0   3.0  15.000000  3.0
3    1.0   1.0  12.000000  3.0
4    NaN   1.0  11.306019  1.0

# 4. Impute color
# training data and targets (color)
x_color = toy_example.values[:, 1:]
y_color = toy_example.values[:, 0]

# discard entries with nan
is_nan = np.isnan(y_color)

x_train = x_color[~is_nan]
y_train = y_color[~is_nan]

# train classifier and impute size
clf = HistGradientBoostingClassifier(l2_regularization=1.0).fit(x_train, y_train)

toy_example.loc[is_nan, 'Color'] = clf.predict(x_color[is_nan])
toy_example
   Color  Size     Weight  Age
0    1.0   1.0  10.000000  2.0
1    2.0   2.0  13.500000  4.0
2    3.0   3.0  15.000000  3.0
3    1.0   1.0  12.000000  3.0
4    1.0   1.0  11.306019  1.0

# 5. Finally, map back to original categories
size_reverse_map = {v: k for k, v in size_map.items()}
color_reverse_map = {v: k for k, v in color_map.items()}

toy_example["Size"] = toy_example["Size"].map(size_reverse_map)
toy_example['Color'] = toy_example["Color"].map(color_reverse_map)
toy_example
```

The final output is the following:

```py
   Color Size     Weight  Age
0   Blue    S  10.000000  2.0
1    Red    M  13.500000  4.0
2  Green    L  15.000000  3.0
3   Blue    S  12.000000  3.0
4   Blue    S  11.306019  1.0
```

Indeed, with more samples and right model capacity you'll get accurate predictions for the missing values.

Comment: Thank you, Luca Anzalone. Your solution was very helpful in resolving the issue I was facing. Although I'm not familiar with the Histogram-based Gradient Boosting classifier, I appreciate the references you provided in the [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#histogram-based-gradient-boosting) and will study them in more detail.

Comment: Also, Luca Anzalone. I want to double check the following: You know if the order of the imputation process affects the result of the imputation? For example, if imputing first a `variable1` and second a `variable2` produces the same imputation as imputing first a `variable2` and second a `variable1`. I check in the case of the `toy_example` and I get the same result when imputing first `Size` and then `Color` in relation to imputing first `Color` and then `Size`. However I don't know if in a general case this is always true.

Comment: For the `KNNImputer` it just reasons on distances so if these are the same despite the variable order you would achieve the same result. For the classifier instead what matters is the correlation between the variables. But in general expect different outcomes.